# If $I$ is finitely generated then $I(\prod_{\lambda}M_{\lambda}) =\prod_{\lambda}(IM_{\lambda})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

> Let $A$ be a ring, let $I$ be an ideal of $A$, and let $Λ$ be
>   a non empty set, and let $M_λ$ be an $A$-module for each $λ ∈ Λ$. If $I$ is finitely generated then $I(\prod_{\lambda}M_{\lambda}) = \prod_{\lambda}(IM_{\lambda})$.

One direction $I(\prod_{\lambda}M_{\lambda}) \subset (\prod_{\lambda}IM_{\lambda})$ is easy. But to show that $I(\prod_{\lambda}M_{\lambda}) \supset (\prod_{\lambda}IM_{\lambda})$ is hard for me. I tried to solve it but I don't know how can I use the hypothesis I is finitely generated. Can anyone give me some hints? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the simplest case where $I$ is generated by just one element $a$, so $I=aA$. Then an element of $\prod_{\lambda}IM_{\lambda}$ is a tuple
indexed by $\lambda$ where each element is some $i_1m_1+\dots+i_km_k =ax_1m_1+\dots+ax_km_k$. So clearly you can pull $a$ out of all these elements and view everything as a member of $I(\prod_{\lambda}M_{\lambda})$.

If that is clear, now look to the case when $I$ is generated by $a_1...a_n$. Again, look at what some element of a tuple in the product looks like - i.e. some element of $IM_\lambda$ for some specific $\lambda$ - and see if you can pull the generating elements out *uniformly* for all those and recombine as an element of $I(\prod_{\lambda}M_{\lambda})$. Don't forget that an element of $I(\prod_{\lambda}M_{\lambda})$ doesn't have to be a simple product of an element of $I$ and an element of $\prod_{\lambda}M_{\lambda}$ - it might be a finite sum of such products. If still having trouble, study the next-simplest case of $I=<a,b> = aA+bA$.